# Docker-compose for microservice application

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, microservices

I have a web appliication, which consists of main server and 5 microservices (Django everywhere). I also have 2 databases (PostgreSQL) and redis working in one of microservices. I also use nginx for main server.
I set up all on remote server and now services run through `tmux` just by commands like that:

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5050 --workers 5 --threads 5 some_service.wsgi
```

Now I think that the whole application must me containerized and I am an absolute beginner in Docker.
As I understand, I need to build docker-compose.yml file and set every entity there. I made Dockerfile for every microservice. They look like:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/main_server
WORKDIR /usr/src/main_server

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /usr/src/main_server
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5001

RUN chmod a+x ./run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

and `run.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

python manage.py collectstatic --settings=main_server.settings.development --noinput
exec gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5001 --workers 5 --threads 5 --timeout 15 main_server.wsgi
```

so for now i made such docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  user_db:
    "????"

  app_db:
    "????"

  redis:
    "????"

  main_server:
    build:
      context: .
        dockerfile: main_server/main_server/Dockerfile

  user_service:
    build:
      context: .
        dockerfile: user_service/user_service/Dockerfile

  session_service:
    build:
      context: .
        dockerfile: session_service/session_service/Dockerfile

  apartment_service:
    build:
      context: .
        dockerfile: apartment_service/apartment_service/Dockerfile

  bill_service:
    build:
      context: .
        dockerfile: utility_bill/utility_bill_service/Dockerfile

  mail_service:
    build:
      context: .
        dockerfile: mail_service/mail_service/Dockerfile
```

As I got after `docker-compose up` for every service will be created a container with settings from Dockerfiles.
But how can I set up my db and redis containers? In django my db settings look like:

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

        'NAME': 'users',

        'USER': 'postgres',

        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXX',

        'HOST': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST', default='localhost'),

        'PORT': '5432',

    }

}
```

And my redis settings in microservice:

```
SESSION_REDIS = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 6379,
    'db': 1,
    'password': '41zipudu',
    'prefix': 'session',
    'socket_timeout': 1,
    'retry_on_timeout': True
    }
```

So how can I correctly set all this stuff?

I also need to make a nginx container, but I don't know how to set up container with existing configs.
So now my app config is located in /etc/nginx/sites-available/main_server:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 134.111.111.22;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;  }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/holyskills/Desktop/SimpleBill/simplebill/main_server/main_server;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_connect_timeout   45;
                proxy_send_timeout      45;
                proxy_read_timeout      45;
                client_max_body_size    15m;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set environmental variables in docker compose for each microservice.

For example:

```
postgres:
    ....

redis:
    ....

main_server:
    build:
      context: .
        dockerfile: main_server/main_server/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      - REDIS_HOST: redis
```

Note the environmental variables matching the names of the postgres and redis docker compose containers above.

Then in the microservices, access those environmental variables where needed. For example in Python:

```
host = os.getenv(POSTGRES_HOST)
```

The addresses of containers in Docker Compose (unless otherwise defined) is the name given to the in docker-compose.yaml. So for example you could ping "main_server" from another container in the compose network.